# Avoid errors from column name, if it doesn't exist in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, so I have a script that is meant to be universal for three different processes that are the same, however the source tables (that have the same name) contain slightly different column definitions.

My case in point is Study1 and Study2.

Study 1 has Table1 that has a column called Site

Study 2 has Table1 that does not have a column called Site.

In the case of Study1, I need to query Site, however it doesn't affect Study2, so I don't need it.

How can I leave the code that checks 'Site' without having to comment it out?

```
Select
  ...
  ...
CASE WHEN STUDY = STUDY1
     CASE
      WHEN SITE = A THEN ..
      WHEN SITE = B THEN ..
      END
    WHEN STUDY = STUDY2 THEN ..
    WHEN STUDY = STUDY3
```

ETC

Comment: Two or three(as per your requirement) different queries in `IF-ELSE` looks to be the best solution.

Comment: Just put a dummy column in the other study tables?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66755/3690